# const for non-reference arguments

Tags: c++, constants

If I have this code:

```
void Foo(aBasicType aIn) //Where aBasicType is int, char etc.
{
    //...
}
```

Is there any point in making it `const aBasicType` since it is going to be copied anyway? One of the reasons I am asking is because I have seen it in 3rd party code and was wondering if there is something I am not aware of.

Comment: Well, for one thing, the variable is presumably being used in the body of the function, and this "const" is an assurance that it's never used with a value different from the one passed — there's a semantic comfort that wherever you see "aIn" in the function you know it has its original value. Don't know if this is the answer, though.

Comment: You can make it `const reference` also.

Comment: go with const unless you need non-const, not the other way around.

Comment: @iammilind: I have seen answers on SO that state it is inefficient to do it for basic types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216948/c-pass-by-const-reference-and-return-by-const-reference/3216992#3216992

Comment: const reference makes sense for some types etc. as it will save you a copy operation (well replace it with the creation of a reference). Yet would be pointless with the small footprint types noted in the question. 
const is a useful indicator a lot of the time that if you use the passed value somewhere near the bottom of a larger function - it will still be the same as when it was passed.

Comment: @Tomalak: What? Putting const on things that don't need to be const is a clear sign of principals being applied without understanding of *why* those constructs are used.

Comment: @Chris: Nonsense. You don't \*need\* `const` on _any_ of your constants. Doesn't mean it's not a good idea... and it certainly doesn't mean you're doing it just because everybody else does.

Comment: This is c++. not erlang. Its not sensible to make pass-by-value variables immutable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It cannot hurt to declare it `const` if you know that your function needs not modify its value during execution.

Note that functions that change their arguments, when arguments are passed by value, should be rare.

Declaring your variable `const` can prevent you from writing `if (aIn = someValue)`.

Comment: OTOH, it exposes implementation details in the interface. What does the caller care whether the implementation modifies a parameter passed by value?

Comment: @Andy: actually, it need not. Top level const qualifiers are ignored by the compiler for the purpose of matching declarations/definitions, therefore it need not be present in the declaration.

Comment: @Benoit: I agree, I wish that `const` was the default, and we had to precise when we want to *mutate* a data. After all, you cannot "polute" a data you are not writing to...

Comment: @Matthieu M. - It's troublesome enough to maintain and navigate among the redundant declarations/definitions without adding differences. Compilers are not the only readers.

Comment: @Andy: don't abuse overloading because you can, and you won't have any issue with top-level const I think. Personally, I just put const in the header too. If the caller does not care, then it can just ignore it.

Comment: @Matthieu M. - I understand what you are saying, but find it easier in practice for the coded signatures of a method to be identical across header and source files -- and across class hierarchies -- and not change because of implementation details. Internal const-checking can still be done with const local variables.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes (infrequently) do it, when there is temptation to modify `aIn` in-place instead of making another copy, yet the method relies on `aIn` remaining unchanged throughout. It tends to be a close call though.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is informative: you want the compiler to warn/error when a value-passed argument is seen on the left of an assignment.
It's a bit cumbersome, seen on libs whose audience may be less than "well informed" on C or C++ (it's the same for both languages).

Answer (score 0):

That would make the value `const` for that function, which might be useful in the same way declaring a constant at the top of your function might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

No, adding const to a scalar call-by-value parameter is meaningless and will only be confusing.

Comment: Agree, information if a function modifies an argument passed by value is of little importance to the caller, additionally such a const is not considered for function overloading.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add const qualifier to input paramters regardless to parameter passing method (by value, by pointer or by reference). So const parameter simply means "input parameter" and non-const parameter means "output parameter" (or, rarely, inout parameter). I suppose such a convention makes code more understandable but it is matter of taste,  of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can formulate this much simpler. When `footype` is not a template parameter:

- `const footype &` in the signature is a guarantee for the caller of
  the function and a constraint for the implementer of the function.
- `const footype` on the other hand is only a constraint for the
  implementer and irrelevant to the caller.

When `footype` is a template parameter, then the rules can only be tested against the individual template instantiations.

BTW, if you see const constraints, then the connected code is much easier to read because the possibilities of what the code can do is much restricted. This is one of the many reasons why C++ is easier to read than C# or Java.