# Why is my Code runing under codeblocks but not in VS Studio

Tags: c++

This line canot pass under VS Studio, But it is running under CodeBlocks.

`cg1.RegisterGoods("c++", 23, 32);`

`'void CGoods::RegisterGoods(char [],int,float)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'char []'`

like so:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class CGoods
{
private:
    char    Name[21];
    int Amount;
    float   Price;
    float   Total_value;

public:
    void  RegisterGoods(char name[], int amount, float price)
    {
        strcpy(Name,name);
        Amount = amount;
        Price = price;
    }
    void  CountTotal(void)
    {
        Total_value = Price * Amount;
    }
    void  GetName(char name[])
    {
        strcpy(name,Name);
    }
    int GetMount(void)
    {
        return Amount;
    }

    float GetPrice(void)
    {
        return Price;
    }
    float GetTotal(void)
    {
        return Total_value;
    }
};

int  main() {
    CGoods cg1;
    cg1.RegisterGoods("c++", 23, 32);
    cout<<cg1.GetPrice()<<endl;
    cout<<cg1.GetMount();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't pass arrays for string literals, use `const char*` isntead.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead*

Comment: That might be because CodeBlocks uses different compiler or compiler settings, and does not enforce that. But a string literal  like `"c++"` is a `const char[4]` and passing it as `char *` violates const correctness. So this should always be handled as an error, even so it is often only handled as warning by compilers and/or IDEs in their default settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char name[]` as a function parameter is equivalent to `char *name` while your string literal has a type `const char [4]` which can only be (safely) converted to `const char *`, so you have to change your parameter like this:

```
void RegisterGoods(const char *name, int amount, float price)
```

and here:

```
 // Renamed to SetName given that it's what this function actually does
void SetName(const char *name)
```

In general though you shouldn't use plain `char` arrays to store strings in C++, you should instead prefer using `std::string`:

```
std::string Name;
...
void SetName(std::string name)
{
    // take advantage of move semantics to avoid redundant copying
    // if you are using C++11 and beyond
    Name = std::move(name);
}
```

Comment: please don't suggest passing a string by-value. better use a const reference.

Comment: @skratchi.at, actually passing by-value should be a default option if this value is then stored since move-semantics were introduces. Read more [here](https://codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog//2012/06/19/efficient-argument-passing-cxx11-part1/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `c`-constructs for things, `c++` has better answers. `char`-pointers can lead to unwanted behaviors and nasty buffer overflow exploits and so on. It is far better to use a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Change your member-function `RegisterGoods` to:

```
void  RegisterGoods(std::string const & name, int const amount, float const price)
{
    Name = name;
    Amount = amount;
    Price = price;
}
```

and your declaration of `Name`to:

```
private:
    std::string Name;
```

your return function `GetName` to:

```
std::string GetName() const
{
    return Name;
}
```

OR

```
void  GetName(std::string & name) const
{
    name = Name;
}
```

also add the include for `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
```

Tip for a better code... [don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). `std` is a enormously huge namespace. Unintentionally you may override a function out of `std` and you end up with a nearly undebuggable error.

Also define your parameters in setter functions as `const`, so you can't change the value of it unintentionally.

Comment: the function `GetName(void)` could be declared `const` (no need for the return type)

Comment: @StackDanny included your comment into my answer

Comment: I mean `std::string GetName() const` instead of `const std::string GetName()`

Comment: thanks for the edit, but the `const`s for the parameters are not unnecessary. you may correct me, but i refused that change

Comment: they are unnecessary as the parameters are not send via reference. Beeing send by value copies them anyway. But you can surely leave it `const` as there is one good reason (for good practise) and that is to avoid cases where one would accidentely assign the paramater like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125425/const-for-non-reference-arguments).

Comment: @StackDanny as the names are very similar, I strongly suggest the `const`. So it is impossible to assign them the wrong way around. It is not only good practice. Also, where is the use in letting them change, when the function is a setter? It lets room for hard to debug mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Is that means that we don't need strcpy and char in c++ anymore? Because i replaced all the 'char' with string and its funktion also. like this:

```
    private:
        std::string Name;
    public:
        void  RegisterGoods(const string name, int amount, float price)
            {
              Name=name;
              Amount = amount;
              Price = price;
            }

        const std::string GetName()
        {
            return Name;
        }
```