# Returning reference to temporary (built in types)

Tags: c++, reference, return, temporary

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339601/warning-returning-reference-to-temporary) it is clear that a string literal cannot be used for a function that returns const string& since there is an implicit conversion from const char* to std::string which creates a temporary.

But then why do I get a warning "warning: returning reference to a temporary" if my return type match exactly and there is no need for conversion, e.g.:

```
include <iostream>

const int& test(){
    return 2;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << test();

}
```

No implicit conversion needed to happen on the return value of 2, so why is there a warning? I thought using test() would be pretty much the same as doing

```
 const int& example = 2;
```

which is perfectly valid. Additionally if I change 2 to 2.2 (so it is a double) the program still runs (with the same warning) despite the fact there IS a conversion from double to int? Shouldn't I be running in to an issue similar to how const char* was returned to the string reference, if there is a conversion from double to int?

Comment: A reference can't bind directly to an rvalue. Instead, a temporary object of type `int` is constructed (inside `test`) and initialized to 2, and a reference to that object is returned. The temporary is destroyed at that very moment, leaving the reference dangling.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I see, thanks. To me, the thread I linked made it seem like this is a problem you only run in to when implicit conversions take place.

Comment: and the "fact" that it "works", well, that's just UB.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6896334/560648 though the answers aren't very good; you need a standard quote, really.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Potentially we could close the question you linked to as a dupe of this one, if the answers are of higher quality here?

Answer (score 1):

A temporary is still created. §8.5.3/(5.2.2.2) applies<sup>1</sup>:

> Otherwise, a temporary of type “ *cv1* `T1`” is created and
>   copy-initialized (8.5) from the initializer expression. The reference
>   is then bound to the temporary.

This also applies in your second example. It does not apply for prvalues of class type, or scalar xvalues: Both

```
const A& a = A();
// and
const int& i = std::move(myint);
```

do not introduce a temporary.  However, that isn't changing the final result : In any case, the temporary that is bound to the reference will be destroyed at the end of the `return` statement - §12.2/(5.2):

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function `return` statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary
>   is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the `return`
>   statement.

**That is, the temporary is destroyed before the function even exits, and thus your program induces undefined behavior.**

---

<sup>1</sup> I could go on and quote the entire list to show why it does, but that would presumably be a waste of answer space.

Answer (score 0):

> an implicit conversion from const char* to std::string which creates a temporary

You are conflating the two topics. Implicit conversions are not the only thing that can create temporaries:

```
const std::string& test() {
    return std::string("no implicit conversions here.");
}
```

There is no implicit conversion to create the `string`, but the created `string` is still temporary, and so you're still returning a reference to a temporary object.

In your example, `2` is still a temporary value, temporarily stored somewhere on the stack, and whose location/address is returned so callers can get at the value, but they are not supposed to.